# C: private variable for process

Tags: c, process, static, mutex, private

Two processes are created .

each of them call function `A` with input 0 ( Function A is in some other .c file).

The variable x needs to be global, however, it should be private for each process.

Since It is `x = y` it seems that each process has its own x. I want to know why? And why z is shared between both process?

```
int x;
int z;
void A(int y)
{
     x = y;
     x++;
     z++;
     B();
}
void B()
{
     x--;
}
```

in main.c

```
//2 process created and each of them call A(0)
```

Comment: are you creating two threads in main?

Comment: 2 process, yes in main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing between processes and executable files.

Each process is a distinct entity that can have binary executable instructions and data from one or more files mapped into its memory.

Even 2 instances(processes) of the same executable will have their own individual copies of all the variables. i.e. variables are NOT shared.

Communicating and sharing data between processes is achieved by various IPC mechanisms as detailed in this **[excellent IPC guide on unix systems by beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

Any sane OS completely separates processes, so one process has by default no access to the others' process memory. If you need more clarifications please ask away.

To clarify - global variables are *not* shared.

Comment: Thanks, But if a global variable exists then it will be shared. why?

Answer (score 1):

For each process . They have there own stack memory. Static value stored in the data segment.And of course belong to process private .

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a process is spawned, it gets its own address space. Address space include data segment, stack segment, heap/bss and code segments. 
In your program, the variable x is global, so it is allocated memory in the data segment of that process.

2 or 100 processes will have their own copy of x in their data segment. This is how any operating system allocates memory to a running process.

If you need to share the variable "x" between processes, then you need to use at least shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you created two threads in main, and you called method A() the following things may happen

1. The execution order of A() method by the two threads is undefined(any thread may start first).
2. For suppose if thread1 executed A() method till X++, and if thread2 started executing A() then thread2 will see x value as 1 not zero( as it is a global variable)
3. If there are any global variables(x,z in this case)two threads share same global values.